# How do i add Firefox extensions to GeckoFX?

Tags: vb.net, firefox, firefox-addon, vb.net-2010, geckofx

i'v been googling around for the whole day searching for a tutorial how to use Firefox extensions in "Geckofx" ( vb.net ) couldn't find any.
anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Can this anonymous down voter help at least ? or state a down vote reason.

Comment: I was not your downvoter, but this is an issue that is probably best brought to the Geckofx repository. It is not really the best kind of question for Stackoverflow. See my answer for some help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to sound less like a request for a tutorial. In addition, it also sounds like this is a general computing question, not specifically about programming. If either of those is the case, the question is off-topic for SatckOverflow. While it is possible that you intended the question to be about programming, that is not clear from the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this ticket in the Geckofx repository. I believe it is the closest answer you will be able to get: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/issues/211/firefox-extension-in-geckofx

This appears to be related to a bug in Geckofx. Here is the most helpful comment on that page:

> First, add the location where the extension is deployed using

```
Xpcom.ComponentRegistrar.AutoRegister():
void RegisterExtensionDir(string dir)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Registering binary extension directory:  " + dir);
    var chromeDir = (nsIFile)Xpcom.NewNativeLocalFile(dir);
    var chromeFile = chromeDir.Clone();
    chromeFile.Append(new nsAString("chrome.manifest"));
    Xpcom.ComponentRegistrar.AutoRegister(chromeFile);
}
```

> Second, do NOT use the ABI flag in the extension's chrome.manifest. So instead of

`binary-component components/GeckoScraper.dll  ABI=WINNT_x86-msvc`

> I used

`binary-component components/GeckoScraper.dll`

Comment: Thank you for your answer i will look further in this.

Comment: This is the same pasted comment from bitbucket and it is not working, have you managed to fix it?